# How to analyze/calculate a lot of csv-logfiles automatically

Tags: csv, data-analysis, batch-processing

I have a bunch of logilfes from machines at my work, and i want to analyze them. These files are named like #increasingnumer_date_time.csv and alltogether these are round about 10.000 files (0.5-2MB each) that contain information about temperatures, pressures, status of actors like vents, pumps, ect.

I want that script to do some calculations (forming integrals of the pressures when special conditions are met) with any of these csv-files and store the result of every calculation in a csv/excel-file in the way, that I have a list of the logfile-names and the corresponding result of the calculation...

So it is not needed to put all these files in one super-big megafile, it is totally fine when these files were opened and processed one-after-another and just every result of the calculation is written in the result-file so that i can allocate the results of the calculation to the corresponding csv-file...

How can I do this? I am no programming expert, but I use python/pandas sometimes...

Thank you

I tried to do it file-after-file using excel :-))
I expect that this is a batch job that can be automated (but I do not know how) :))

Comment: Using Python, you should take a look at [glob](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-python-glob-module-47d82f4cbd2d), which makes it simple to iterate over a list of files. To get further help, it would be good to have examples of input and desired output. (give a few trivial examples).

Comment: Sorry I cannot give the real data as example, since they are confidential.

Imagine thousands of csv-files named 1.csv , 2.csv, ..., (n).csv
Every file contains tousands of numbers, that represent continuously measured values of different sensors and actors every second. 
For simplicity lets think of file 1.csv like the following:
- pressure  ; temperature ; sensor x ; sensor y
- 5 ; 10 ; 2 ; 6
- 6 ; 11 ; 2 ; 7
- 6 ; 11 ; 2 ; 7

Now I want to calculate lets say for simplicity the sum of all pressures, so for this this example-file it would be 5+6+6 = 17. So 17 is the result f. 1.csv.

Comment: All I want the script to do is
- open the first file
- do the calculation-stuff
- save the result and the corresponding filename
- close the file because we are done with it
- repeat this until this is done with all the files in the directory

And the resulting file should look like:
- filename ; result
- 1.csv ; 17
- 2.csv ; 46
- ...
- (last).csv ; result of the calculation in the last file

Comment: The real calculation is way more complex and I will change some boundary conditions to analyze the effect on the results, so I will run this whole thing several times, but
no iteration and no fancy linking between the files is needed, its just a big bunch of calculations that follow the algorithm "open file->calculate this and that->close file->save the result->repeat with next file". Normally I would do this calculation easy-peasy with excel, but I dont want do open thousands of files and do the same stuff over and over  :-)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: that's kind of what I was trying to refer you to. Look at `glob`, it's probably what you want. Glob gives you an iterable list of files, onto which you can call a function: `do_process(filename)`. It does not matter what the function does to the file actually.